# Oracle Query to generate dates and calculated charge based on day range and invoice tables

Tags: oracle

Can anyone assist me to build an oracle query for below expected result that
I have 2 tables, Named as **detention_charge_slot** and **detention_invoice** example as follows

```
create table detention_charge_slot
        (slot_no number(5),
        from_days number(10),
        to_days number(10),
        charge_amount number(10,2));

insert into detention_charge_slot
        values (1,1,4,0);

        insert into detention_charge_slot
        values (2,5,9,10);

        insert into detention_charge_slot
        values (3,10,14,20);

        insert into detention_charge_slot
        values (4,15,999,25);

create table detention_invoice
        (invoice_no number(10),
        invoice_dt date,
        delivery_dt date);
insert into detention_invoice
        values(1,'10-JAN-2015','25-JAN-2015');
```

Now I want to write a query for invoice_no=1,which will give me the below result

```
Start_date | End_date |   Days| Charge_Amount
10-JAN-2015  13-JAN-2015    4      0
14-JAN-2015  18-JAN-2015    5     10
19-JAN-2015  23-JAN-2015    5     20
24-JAN-2015  25-JAN-2015    2     25
```

Comment: Are you familiar with PL/SQL ? You will need that to generate such table.

Answer (score 0):

Predicates in a SQL query can be based on an expression, e.g.:

```
SELECT Charge
FROM   date_range_charge
WHERE  From_days <= (TO_DATE(:param2,'DD-MON-YYYY') 
                     - TO_DATE(:param1,'DD-MON-YYYY') + 1)
AND    To_days   >= (TO_DATE(:param2,'DD-MON-YYYY')
                     - TO_DATE(:param1,'DD-MON-YYYY') + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, Your Query result will be a single value but i'm expecting dates with slot wise charges

Comment: No, you said you wanted some code that would take two parameters "in query like &param1= '10-JAN-2015' and &param2='25-JAN-2015'.". If you want this to run for a number of date ranges stored in another table, you simply need to join to that table and substitute Start_date and End_date for the two parameters.

Comment: i want conditional(based on predefined period in table) date range as above example between two date parameters. here connect by clause may be used but don't know actually.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. For further help please update your question with a complete test case - i.e. CREATE TABLE commands, sample data, and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
select invoice_dt + from_days - 1 start_date, 
    invoice_dt + to_days -1 end_date, 
    to_days-from_days + 1 days, charge_amount
  from detention_charge_slot dcs
    join detention_invoice di on (di.invoice_no = 1)
  order by slot_no

result: 
START_DATE  END_DATE   DAYS CHARGE_AMOUNT
2015-01-10  2015-01-13    4          0,00
2015-01-14  2015-01-18    5         10,00
2015-01-19  2015-01-23    5         20,00
2015-01-24  2017-10-04  985         25,00
```

The last row is different, because you put 999 in `detention_charge_slot.to_days`. If you want 2 there then modify query like here:

```
select invoice_dt + from_days - 1 start_date, 
    least(invoice_dt + to_days - 1, delivery_dt) end_date, 
    least(invoice_dt + to_days - 1, delivery_dt) - (invoice_dt + from_days - 2) days, 
    charge_amount
  from detention_charge_slot dcs
    join detention_invoice di on (di.invoice_no = 1)
  order by slot_no

result: 
START_DATE  END_DATE   DAYS CHARGE_AMOUNT
2015-01-10  2015-01-13    4          0,00
2015-01-14  2015-01-18    5         10,00
2015-01-19  2015-01-23    5         20,00
2015-01-24  2015-01-25    2         25,00
```